# Applying a custom function to a data.table doesn't work, even though the function seems okay individually

Tags: r, data.table, sentiment-analysis

tl,dr: My function seems to work, but then I lapply it and it doesn't. Is it the function or the lapplying?

#### The data

I have a datatable that contains text which is already tokenised into a character vector:

```
   id                   text
1:  1    c("sadness", "joy")
2:  2   c("anger", "scream")
3:  3 c("relief", "sadness")
```

I want to annotate my tokenised texts with emotional values with a dictionary that has words and associated emotional values:

```
     words emotion1 emotion2
1: sadness        1        5
2:   anger        2        6
3:  relief        3        7
```

#### The ultimate goal

I am expecting my search_function to output something similar to this:

```
my_emotion_function(c("relief", "sadness"), lexicon_emotions)
   emotion1 emotion2
1:        2        6
my_emotion_function(c("relief", "meh"), lexicon_emotions)
   emotion1 emotion2
1:        3        7
my_emotion_function(c("meh", "ugh"), lexicon_emotions)
   emotion1 emotion2
1:       NA       NA
```

Applying this to the tokens, I would add new columns and fill them with the results.

```
  id               text     emotion1 emotion2
1:  1  c("sadness", "joy")         1        5
2:  2  c("anger", "scream")        2        6
3:  3  c("relief", "sadness")      2        6
```

#### The function that half-works

The function takes a character vector, subsets the (keyed) emotional dictionary for matching words and calculates the average score for each emotional dimension.

```
my_emotion_function <- function(characters, lexicon){
  return(lexicon[.(characters), lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = 2:3])
}
```

#### What I don't understand

What I am baffled by and can't understand is why this function seems to work well when tested on one character vector (the example above, testing it only on one vector, works well), but when I want to lapply it to a data.table, it doens't work.
I am not sure whether the function is wrong in one aspect or my laplying of it to the data.table. I can't figure out why the single instance works, but not repeatedly on a data.table

If I execute the above code, with an equal number of tokens in each "text" row, then I will just get N.A for every cell, no matter the words.

```
   id                   text emotion1 emotion2
1:  1    c("sadness", "joy")      NaN      NaN
2:  2   c("anger", "scream")      NaN      NaN
3:  3 c("relief", "sadness")      NaN      NaN
```

If you test it out with an unequal number of tokens (say the first row), then every row contains the value for the first row.

```
   id                   text emotion1 emotion2
1:  1                sadness        1        5
2:  2   c("anger", "scream")        1        5
3:  3 c("relief", "sadness")        1        5
```

I can't find a reason as to why I either get only the same result or NA's everywhere.

#### Complete code for reproduction

```
library(data.table)
table_of_tokens <- data.table("id" = 1:3,
                              "text" = list(c("sadness", "joy"),
                                            c("anger", "scream"),
                                            c("relief", "sadness")))
table_of_tokens[, "text" := as.character(text)]
#convert to character vector to use key-subsetting in data.table

lexicon_emotions <-
  data.table(
    "words" = c("sadness", "anger", "relief"),
    "emotion1" = 1:3,
    "emotion2" = 5:7
  )
setkey(lexicon_emotions, words)

my_emotion_function <- function(characters, lexicon) {
  return(lexicon[.(characters), 
                 lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = 2:3])
}
table_of_tokens[, c("emotion1", "emotion2") := 
                  my_emotion_function(text, lexicon_emotions)]
```

*Credit: this is a basically a re-write of the [syuzhet](https://github.com/mjockers/syuzhet) R-package, which relies on data.frames and is therefore not flexible or efficient enough in my situation for a large dataset.*

Comment: I think part of the problem you're having is that you've converted `table_of_tokens$text` from a list of character vectors into a vector of character strings. `table_of_tokens[2,2][[1]]` for example evaluates to `"c(\"anger\", \"scream\")"`. Can you explain why you needed to do this?

Comment: @IanCampbell As far as I understand, subsetting a data.table with a key only works with a vector, not a list? `lexicon_emotions[.(c("sadness", "grief"))]` works, but `lexicon_emotions[.(list("grief", "anger"))]` tells me that _i.V1 is type list which is not supported by data.table join_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most important aspects of code writing is debugging. Let's use a simple `print()` call to figure out what is happening during the function call:

```r
my_emotion_function <- function(characters, lexicon) {
  print(characters) ## for debugging
  return(lexicon[.(characters), 
                 lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = 2:3])
}

table_of_tokens[, c("emotion1", "emotion2") := 
                  my_emotion_function(text, lexicon_emotions)]

## [1] "c(\"sadness\", \"joy\")"    "c(\"anger\", \"scream\")"   "c(\"relief\", \"sadness\")"
```

What that means is that we are are actually performing:

```
lexicon["c(\"sadness\", \"joy\")" ...]

## what we actually want for each token

lexicon[c("sadness", "joy"), lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = 2:3])
```

To do so, we *do **not** want to convert from a list to a character* as suggested by @IanCampbell. The other item is that we want to loop through each element, which means `lapply()` can be our friend:

```r
table_of_tokens[, c("emotion1", "emotion2") := 
                  rbindlist(lapply(text, my_emotion_function, lexicon_emotions))]
table_of_tokens

##    id           text emotion1 emotion2
## 1:  1    sadness,joy        1        5
## 2:  2   anger,scream        2        6
## 3:  3 relief,sadness        2        6
```

I am still uncertain what would happen if there were no matches.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am afraid that in my case, I want as many results as possible to match for more precise emotion detection, and my emotional dictionary is quite large.

Comment: Could you edit your question to reproduce that criteria? In your example, it was a one to one match. It is ok if it is one to many, but your example should reflect that.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you meant that for every character I could have more than one match? No, every entry in the dictionary I look up must be unique, sorry, I misunderstood you there (sadness can only have pair of emotional values). What I meant is that ine one row of table_tokens, there might be multiple characters that match. In the edited example, in the last row, both relief and sadness match dictionary entries.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Can you include expected results?

Comment: Thank you for your engagement! I have added some examples for the individual function output and the whole data.table. Do you need more? 
Basically I believe my_emotion_function works, but not on a data.table. And I am not sure whether I am making a mistake in the function or when applying it to a data.table.

Comment: The mistake seems to largely come from Ian Campbell's note of what `as.character(list(c("sad", "angry")))` actually does. Also see edits.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I had noticed that formatting, but didn't consider how it might be problematic. Reading up on data-types goes on my list...and what an easy solution!
Actually, if there are no matches found, it returns a data.table with a row filled with NAs. Thats why I am going with the key-ing approach over `string %%chin% words` because that returns an empty data.table. The only thing I need to check for is when I encounter an empty string (e.g. aggressive pre-processing), to also return an NA. data.table there.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: this should get you want you want.

```r
library(data.table)
table_of_tokens <- data.table(
    "id" = 1:3,
    "text" = list(
        c("sadness"), 
        c("anger", "scream"),
        c("relief", "grief"),
        c("relief", "grief", "sadness")
    )
)

lexicon_emotions <- data.table("words" = c("sadness", "anger", "relief"), 
                                                             "emotion1" = 1:3,
                                                             "emotion2" = 5:7,
                                                             key = "words")


emotions <- names(lexicon_emotions)[-1]
table_of_tokens[,
    (emotions) := {
        res <- lapply(text, function(x) {
            lexicon_emotions[words %chin% x,
                             lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE),
                             .SDcols = emotions]
        })
        rbindlist(res)
    }
]

print(table_of_tokens)
```

```r
> print(table_of_tokens)
   id                 text emotion1 emotion2
1:  1              sadness        1        5
2:  2         anger,scream        2        6
3:  3         relief,grief        3        7
4:  1 relief,grief,sadness        2        6
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I feel like I would lose a bit of information without the column names but I can definitely live with that. However, in your example, with `"relief", "grief", "sadness"` in the third row, the end result should actually be the average score, in this case 2, 6; not 3, 7, which ignores the sadness occuring later in the third row.
For that, `emo1 <- vapply(res, `[`, numeric(1), 1)` would need to pick out every even element in the lists and then calculate the mean; similiarly for emo2 every odd-element.

Comment: Oh i get what are saying, gimme a second

Comment: Thank you! Feels extremely validated, with both Cole and you coming to essentially the same conclusion. I love the `emotions<- names()` line, that is more elegant than my initial approach and goes straight into my code. Guess I need to think a bit more about how I attach new columns to a data.table...